# Prove $P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n} F_{j}\right) \geq \sum_{j=1}^{n} P\left(F_{j}\right)-(n-1)$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I want to prove the following for any finite sequence of events $F_1,...F_n$.

$$P\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{n} F_{j}\right) \geq \sum_{j=1}^{n} P\left(F_{j}\right)-(n-1)$$

How to do this?

Comment: Perhaps use an inductive argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $P(A \cap B) \ge P(A) + P(B) - 1$. (Why?) Now perform induction and use $A = \bigcup_{k=1}^{j=1} F_j$ and $B = F_n$

Answer (score 0):

$HINT$

$$P([\bigcap_{j=1}^nF_j]^c)=P([\bigcup_{j=1}^nF_j^c]) \leq \sum_{j=1}^{n}(1-P(F_j))$$

$$P([\bigcap_{j=1}^nF_j]^c)=1-P([\bigcap_{j=1}^nF_j])$$